# How is the code divided upon threads in multithreaded environments?

Tags: c, multithreading

In multithreaded environments, is there a way to find out how many threads are going to execute the code. Is every line of code a candidate for being run with a different thread ? What determines the number of lines that each thread will run ?

Comment: What do you mean by "how many threads"? The code is going to use as many thread as you tell it to. Or do you expect the compiler to automagically split your code onto multiple threads?

Comment: I think when running(after the compilation) an application, it will not be run by a single thread ? Or for example in Java if you use the multicore VM and run an application, this will automatically use multiple threads.

Comment: If you write your code to be single-threaded it is going to be run by a single thread. If your code is multi-threaded it is going to be executed on multiple threads. Automatically multi-threading code is an active area of research but still difficult to pull off in practice, as it requires a ton of code analysis.

Comment: I think that if you write code without specifying threads, it will be run by multiple threads. Otherwise, why would we need mutexes in case of manipulating elements to a list which is static and global

Comment: @Bionix1441 "I think that if you write code without specifying threads, it will be run by multiple threads." No, that is nonsense. "Otherwise, why would we need mutexes in case of manipulating elements to a list which is static and global" The only reason why you would do that, is because you are writing code that you expect to be executed by multi-threaded programs.